# How do I change the color of the axes of a matplotlib 3D plot?

Tags: matplotlib

I have set

```
import matplotlib as mpl
AXES_COLOR = '#333333'
mpl.rc('axes', edgecolor=AXES_COLOR, labelcolor=AXES_COLOR, grid=True)
mpl.rc('xtick', color=AXES_COLOR)
mpl.rc('ytick', color=AXES_COLOR)
mpl.rc('grid', color=AXES_COLOR)
```

The color of the axes labels and the ticks are properly set both in 2D and in 3D.  However, the `edgecolor` doesn't apply to 3D axes and they remain black.  Likewise, the grid isn't affected.

I think figured out how to access the individual axes of a 3D plot:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import mpl_toolkits.mplot3d # Needed for 3d projection.
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.w_zaxis # <- the z axis
```

The [documentation](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/api.html#module-mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axis3d) mentions a property that we can use until the developers have finished refactoring their 3D code:

```
import pprint
pprint.pprint(ax.w_xaxis._AXINFO)

{'x': {'color': (0.95, 0.95, 0.95, 0.5),
       'i': 0,
       'juggled': (1, 0, 2),
       'tickdir': 1},
 'y': {'color': (0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.5),
       'i': 1,
       'juggled': (0, 1, 2),
       'tickdir': 0},
 'z': {'color': (0.925, 0.925, 0.925, 0.5),
       'i': 2,
       'juggled': (0, 2, 1),
       'tickdir': 0}}
```

However, the color parameter changes the color of the background of the axes planes (between the wired of the grid), not the color of the edges of these planes.

Am I digging too deep ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out it's impossible since these values are hard-coded.  [This archived email from the matplotlib-users mailing list](http://www.mail-archive.com/matplotlib-users@lists.sourceforge.net/msg20355.html) helped me.  Here's the relevant part:

> Unfortunately, you have stumbled upon one of the ugliness of the mplot3d
>   implementation.  I am hoping to have more control available for the next
>   release.  But right now, there is no way to turn off the axes spines
>   (because they aren't implemented as spines).  If you really want to dig into
>   the source code, you could change the color argument to the Line2D call in
>   the init3d() method in matplotlib/lib/mpl_toolkits/axis3d.py

Although this answer was addressing another concern, it sent me to the direction of `axis3d.py`.  I found it in `/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d`.  I made a backup of the original `axis3d.py` and I moved `axis3d.pyc` away.

Since the code is pretty short and fairly well written it didn't take long to locate the two lines I had to change.

- To change the color of the edges of the individual axes, I modified the `self.line=...` in `__init__`: just replace `color=(0, 0, 0, 1)` by `color=(1, 0, 0, 1)` for a horribly flashy red.  Components of the tuple are red, green, blue, alpha, all floats from 0 to 1.
- To change the color of the grid, I modified the `draw` method.  I replaced the color `self.gridlines.set_color([(0.9,0.9,0.9,1)] * len(lines))` by something of my choosing.

And that's it, it just works.  Not the most convenient, but it's not more work than editing a rc configuration file.

I did not recreate a `.pyc` file.  It does not recreate itself because I do not run my python code as root.  I don't mind the extra milliseconds that python needs to recompile the `.py` each time.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of changing axis3d.py try this: `ax.w_xaxis.line.set_color("red")`

Comment: `ax.w_xaxis` does not exist anymore