# Changing the background color of the axes planes of a 3D plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter-plot, matplotlib-3d

On the basis of the [scatterplot example](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html#scatter-plots) of matplotlib, how can I change the gray background color of the 3 axes grid planes? I would like to set it to white, keeping the grid lines with the default gray color.
I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9215512/how-do-i-change-the-color-of-the-axes-of-a-matplotlib-3d-plot) but I couldn't apply it to the example.
Thanks.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Using the same example. You can set the pane color using the `set_pane_color` method as described here http://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/api.html#axis3d. You can set the color using the RGBA tuple:

```
# scatter3d_demo.py
# ...
# Set the background color of the pane YZ
ax.w_xaxis.set_pane_color((1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0))
plt.show()
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks. Doing the same for yaxis and zaxis is pretty straightforward

Answer (score 41):

For a slightly different approach, see below:

```
# Get rid of colored axes planes
# First remove fill
ax.xaxis.pane.fill = False
ax.yaxis.pane.fill = False
ax.zaxis.pane.fill = False

# Now set color to white (or whatever is "invisible")
ax.xaxis.pane.set_edgecolor('w')
ax.yaxis.pane.set_edgecolor('w')
ax.zaxis.pane.set_edgecolor('w')

# Bonus: To get rid of the grid as well:
ax.grid(False)
```

See this [blog post](https://dawes.wordpress.com/2014/06/27/publication-ready-3d-figures-from-matplotlib/) that I used as my source.

Comment: The command `set_edgecolor` did not work for me on Linux. Hopefully, I found `ax.set_axis_off()` to be effective at removing the axes and the background at all :)

Comment: Using PyPlot.jl in julia, the command set_edgecolor does not work either. But the ax.set_axis_off() works perfectly.

Comment: `set_edgecolor()` works fine on my Linux machine.  The only drawback is that if you want a tight layout, a large seemingly empty white pane remains where white lines are invisibly drawn onto the white background...