# matplotlib surface plot hides scatter points which should be in front

Tags: python, matplotlib

Yet another question about matplotlib 3d surfaces... I have code which adds a scatter point to a matplotlib surface graph.

[image: from above]
The problem that I have is that the point **always** appears behind the surface, regardless of which angle you view it from. [image: from below]

If I cobble an (admittedly ugly) version using 3 short lines to mark the same point, it is visible.
[image]

I have turned off the `depthshade` function, so it isn't this. Can anybody explain what is going on and how I can correct it? Here is a simplified version of the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({10: {10: 1,15: 1,20: 1,25: 1,30: 1,35: 1,40: 1,45: 1,50: 1,55: 1,60: 1,65: 1,70: 1,75: 1,80: 1,85: 1,90: 1},
                   15: {10: 4,15: 1,20: 1,25: 1,30: 1,35: 1,40: 1,45: 1,50: 1,55: 1,60: 1,65: 1,70: 1,75: 1,80: 1,85: 1,90: 1},
                   20: {10: 6,15: 3,20: 1,25: 1,30: 1,35: 1,40: 1,45: 1,50: 1,55: 1,60: 1,65: 1,70: 1,75: 1,80: 1,85: 1,90: 1},
                   25: {10: 7,15: 5,20: 3,25: 1,30: 1,35: 1,40: 1,45: 1,50: 1,55: 1,60: 1,65: 1,70: 1,75: 1,80: 1,85: 1,90: 1},
                   30: {10: 9,15: 6,20: 4,25: 3,30: 1,35: 1,40: 1,45: 1,50: 1,55: 1,60: 1,65: 1,70: 1,75: 1,80: 1,85: 1,90: 1},
                   35: {10: 10,15: 7,20: 5,25: 4,30: 2,35: 1,40: 1,45: 1,50: 1,55: 1,60: 1,65: 1,70: 1,75: 1,80: 1,85: 1,90: 1},
                   40: {10: 11,15: 8,20: 6,25: 4,30: 3,35: 2,40: 1,45: 1,50: 1,55: 1,60: 1,65: 1,70: 1,75: 1,80: 1,85: 1,90: 1},
                   45: {10: 12,15: 9,20: 7,25: 5,30: 4,35: 3,40: 2,45: 1,50: 1,55: 1,60: 1,65: 1,70: 1,75: 1,80: 1,85: 1,90: 1},
                   50: {10: 13,15: 9,20: 7,25: 6,30: 5,35: 4,40: 3,45: 2,50: 1,55: 1,60: 1,65: 1,70: 1,75: 1,80: 1,85: 1,90: 1},
                   55: {10: 14,15: 10,20: 8,25: 7,30: 5,35: 4,40: 3,45: 3,50: 2,55: 1,60: 1,65: 1,70: 1,75: 1,80: 1,85: 1,90: 1},
                   60: {10: 15,15: 11,20: 9,25: 7,30: 6,35: 5,40: 4,45: 3,50: 3,55: 2,60: 1,65: 1,70: 1,75: 1,80: 1,85: 1,90: 1},
                   65: {10: 16,15: 12,20: 9,25: 8,30: 6,35: 5,40: 5,45: 4,50: 3,55: 2,60: 2,65: 1,70: 1,75: 1,80: 1,85: 1,90: 1},
                   70: {10: 17,15: 12,20: 10,25: 8,30: 7,35: 6,40: 5,45: 4,50: 4,55: 3,60: 2,65: 2,70: 1,75: 1,80: 1,85: 1,90: 1},
                   75: {10: 18,15: 13,20: 10,25: 9,30: 7,35: 6,40: 5,45: 5,50: 4,55: 3,60: 3,65: 2,70: 2,75: 1,80: 1,85: 1,90: 1},
                   80: {10: 19,15: 14,20: 11,25: 9,30: 8,35: 7,40: 6,45: 5,50: 4,55: 4,60: 3,65: 3,70: 2,75: 2,80: 1,85: 1,90: 1},
                   85: {10: 21,15: 14,20: 11,25: 10,30: 8,35: 7,40: 6,45: 6,50: 5,55: 4,60: 4,65: 3,70: 3,75: 2,80: 2,85: 1,90: 1},
                   90: {10: 23,15: 15,20: 12,25: 10,30: 9,35: 8,40: 7,45: 6,50: 5,55: 5,60: 4,65: 3,70: 3,75: 3,80: 2,85: 2,90: 1}})




xv, yv = np.meshgrid(df.index, df.columns)
ma = np.nanmax(df.values)
norm = matplotlib.colors.Normalize(vmin = 0, vmax = ma, clip = True)

fig = plt.figure(1)
ax = Axes3D(fig)
surf = ax.plot_surface(yv,xv,df, cmap='viridis_r', linewidth=0.3,
                       alpha = 0.8, edgecolor = 'k', norm=norm)
ax.scatter(25,35,4, c='k', depthshade=False, alpha = 1, s=100)

fig = plt.figure(2)
ax = Axes3D(fig)
surf = ax.plot_surface(yv,xv,df, cmap='viridis_r', linewidth=0.3,
                       alpha = 0.8, edgecolor = 'k', norm=norm)
line1_x = [25,25]
line1_y = [35,35]
line1_z = [3,5]

line2_x = [25,25]
line2_y = [33,37]
line2_z = [4,4]

line3_x = [23,27]
line3_y = [35,35]
line3_z = [4,4]

ax.plot(line1_x, line1_y, line1_z, alpha = 1, linewidth = 1, color='k')
ax.plot(line2_x, line2_y, line2_z, alpha = 1, linewidth = 1, color='k')
ax.plot(line3_x, line3_y, line3_z, alpha = 1, linewidth = 1, color='k')
plt.show()
```

Comment: This is probably this known [issue with 3D projections.](https://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/faq.html#my-3d-plot-doesn-t-look-right-at-certain-viewing-angles)

Comment: is there an established workaround?

Comment: The matplotlib documentation suggests MayaVi, so I guess not within matplotlib.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK, so as per the comment by [Mr T](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8881141/mr-t) above, there doesn't seem to be a **direct** method of dealing with this. There is however, a workaround for what I'm trying to do (highlight specific points on the surface). Using the `matplotlib.patches` and `mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.art3d` modules, it is possible to plot a circle on the graph at the appropriate point, and this appears to be unaffected by the same issue.

[image: an example of "there I fixed it"]

The modified code is:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D, art3d
from matplotlib.patches import Circle
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({10: {10: 1,15: 1,20: 1,25: 1,30: 1,35: 1,40: 1,45: 1,50: 1,55: 1,60: 1,65: 1,70: 1,75: 1,80: 1,85: 1,90: 1},
                   15: {10: 4,15: 1,20: 1,25: 1,30: 1,35: 1,40: 1,45: 1,50: 1,55: 1,60: 1,65: 1,70: 1,75: 1,80: 1,85: 1,90: 1},
                   20: {10: 6,15: 3,20: 1,25: 1,30: 1,35: 1,40: 1,45: 1,50: 1,55: 1,60: 1,65: 1,70: 1,75: 1,80: 1,85: 1,90: 1},
                   25: {10: 7,15: 5,20: 3,25: 1,30: 1,35: 1,40: 1,45: 1,50: 1,55: 1,60: 1,65: 1,70: 1,75: 1,80: 1,85: 1,90: 1},
                   30: {10: 9,15: 6,20: 4,25: 3,30: 1,35: 1,40: 1,45: 1,50: 1,55: 1,60: 1,65: 1,70: 1,75: 1,80: 1,85: 1,90: 1},
                   35: {10: 10,15: 7,20: 5,25: 4,30: 2,35: 1,40: 1,45: 1,50: 1,55: 1,60: 1,65: 1,70: 1,75: 1,80: 1,85: 1,90: 1},
                   40: {10: 11,15: 8,20: 6,25: 4,30: 3,35: 2,40: 1,45: 1,50: 1,55: 1,60: 1,65: 1,70: 1,75: 1,80: 1,85: 1,90: 1},
                   45: {10: 12,15: 9,20: 7,25: 5,30: 4,35: 3,40: 2,45: 1,50: 1,55: 1,60: 1,65: 1,70: 1,75: 1,80: 1,85: 1,90: 1},
                   50: {10: 13,15: 9,20: 7,25: 6,30: 5,35: 4,40: 3,45: 2,50: 1,55: 1,60: 1,65: 1,70: 1,75: 1,80: 1,85: 1,90: 1},
                   55: {10: 14,15: 10,20: 8,25: 7,30: 5,35: 4,40: 3,45: 3,50: 2,55: 1,60: 1,65: 1,70: 1,75: 1,80: 1,85: 1,90: 1},
                   60: {10: 15,15: 11,20: 9,25: 7,30: 6,35: 5,40: 4,45: 3,50: 3,55: 2,60: 1,65: 1,70: 1,75: 1,80: 1,85: 1,90: 1},
                   65: {10: 16,15: 12,20: 9,25: 8,30: 6,35: 5,40: 5,45: 4,50: 3,55: 2,60: 2,65: 1,70: 1,75: 1,80: 1,85: 1,90: 1},
                   70: {10: 17,15: 12,20: 10,25: 8,30: 7,35: 6,40: 5,45: 4,50: 4,55: 3,60: 2,65: 2,70: 1,75: 1,80: 1,85: 1,90: 1},
                   75: {10: 18,15: 13,20: 10,25: 9,30: 7,35: 6,40: 5,45: 5,50: 4,55: 3,60: 3,65: 2,70: 2,75: 1,80: 1,85: 1,90: 1},
                   80: {10: 19,15: 14,20: 11,25: 9,30: 8,35: 7,40: 6,45: 5,50: 4,55: 4,60: 3,65: 3,70: 2,75: 2,80: 1,85: 1,90: 1},
                   85: {10: 21,15: 14,20: 11,25: 10,30: 8,35: 7,40: 6,45: 6,50: 5,55: 4,60: 4,65: 3,70: 3,75: 2,80: 2,85: 1,90: 1},
                   90: {10: 23,15: 15,20: 12,25: 10,30: 9,35: 8,40: 7,45: 6,50: 5,55: 5,60: 4,65: 3,70: 3,75: 3,80: 2,85: 2,90: 1}})




xv, yv = np.meshgrid(df.index, df.columns)
ma = np.nanmax(df.values)
norm = matplotlib.colors.Normalize(vmin = 0, vmax = ma, clip = True)

fig = plt.figure(1)
ax = Axes3D(fig)
surf = ax.plot_surface(yv,xv,df, cmap='viridis_r', linewidth=0.3,
                       alpha = 0.8, edgecolor = 'k', norm=norm)

p = Circle((25, 35), 3, ec='k', fc="none")
ax.add_patch(p)
art3d.pathpatch_2d_to_3d(p, z=4, zdir="z")

plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks for the workaround. I'm facing the same issue in 2020, really wish there's a better solution

Answer (score 10):

A useful workaround is to use the option `computed_zorder=False` (added in [Feb 2021](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/14508/files), see [doc](https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/api/_as_gen/mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d.Axes3D.html#mpl-toolkits-mplot3d-axes3d-axes3d)), and to plot the different elements in the desired order. The only caveat is that it requires knowing which points are below the surface, and which points are above.

[image: Et Voilà !]

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({10: {10: 1,15: 1,20: 1,25: 1,30: 1,35: 1,40: 1,45: 1,50: 1,55: 1,60: 1,65: 1,70: 1,75: 1,80: 1,85: 1,90: 1},
                   15: {10: 4,15: 1,20: 1,25: 1,30: 1,35: 1,40: 1,45: 1,50: 1,55: 1,60: 1,65: 1,70: 1,75: 1,80: 1,85: 1,90: 1},
                   20: {10: 6,15: 3,20: 1,25: 1,30: 1,35: 1,40: 1,45: 1,50: 1,55: 1,60: 1,65: 1,70: 1,75: 1,80: 1,85: 1,90: 1},
                   25: {10: 7,15: 5,20: 3,25: 1,30: 1,35: 1,40: 1,45: 1,50: 1,55: 1,60: 1,65: 1,70: 1,75: 1,80: 1,85: 1,90: 1},
                   30: {10: 9,15: 6,20: 4,25: 3,30: 1,35: 1,40: 1,45: 1,50: 1,55: 1,60: 1,65: 1,70: 1,75: 1,80: 1,85: 1,90: 1},
                   35: {10: 10,15: 7,20: 5,25: 4,30: 2,35: 1,40: 1,45: 1,50: 1,55: 1,60: 1,65: 1,70: 1,75: 1,80: 1,85: 1,90: 1},
                   40: {10: 11,15: 8,20: 6,25: 4,30: 3,35: 2,40: 1,45: 1,50: 1,55: 1,60: 1,65: 1,70: 1,75: 1,80: 1,85: 1,90: 1},
                   45: {10: 12,15: 9,20: 7,25: 5,30: 4,35: 3,40: 2,45: 1,50: 1,55: 1,60: 1,65: 1,70: 1,75: 1,80: 1,85: 1,90: 1},
                   50: {10: 13,15: 9,20: 7,25: 6,30: 5,35: 4,40: 3,45: 2,50: 1,55: 1,60: 1,65: 1,70: 1,75: 1,80: 1,85: 1,90: 1},
                   55: {10: 14,15: 10,20: 8,25: 7,30: 5,35: 4,40: 3,45: 3,50: 2,55: 1,60: 1,65: 1,70: 1,75: 1,80: 1,85: 1,90: 1},
                   60: {10: 15,15: 11,20: 9,25: 7,30: 6,35: 5,40: 4,45: 3,50: 3,55: 2,60: 1,65: 1,70: 1,75: 1,80: 1,85: 1,90: 1},
                   65: {10: 16,15: 12,20: 9,25: 8,30: 6,35: 5,40: 5,45: 4,50: 3,55: 2,60: 2,65: 1,70: 1,75: 1,80: 1,85: 1,90: 1},
                   70: {10: 17,15: 12,20: 10,25: 8,30: 7,35: 6,40: 5,45: 4,50: 4,55: 3,60: 2,65: 2,70: 1,75: 1,80: 1,85: 1,90: 1},
                   75: {10: 18,15: 13,20: 10,25: 9,30: 7,35: 6,40: 5,45: 5,50: 4,55: 3,60: 3,65: 2,70: 2,75: 1,80: 1,85: 1,90: 1},
                   80: {10: 19,15: 14,20: 11,25: 9,30: 8,35: 7,40: 6,45: 5,50: 4,55: 4,60: 3,65: 3,70: 2,75: 2,80: 1,85: 1,90: 1},
                   85: {10: 21,15: 14,20: 11,25: 10,30: 8,35: 7,40: 6,45: 6,50: 5,55: 4,60: 4,65: 3,70: 3,75: 2,80: 2,85: 1,90: 1},
                   90: {10: 23,15: 15,20: 12,25: 10,30: 9,35: 8,40: 7,45: 6,50: 5,55: 5,60: 4,65: 3,70: 3,75: 3,80: 2,85: 2,90: 1}})




xv, yv = np.meshgrid(df.index, df.columns)
ma = np.nanmax(df.values)
norm = matplotlib.colors.Normalize(vmin = 0, vmax = ma, clip = True)

fig = plt.figure(1)
ax = Axes3D(fig, computed_zorder=False)

ax.scatter(10,70,4, c='k', depthshade=False, alpha = 1, s=100)
surf = ax.plot_surface(yv,xv,df, cmap='viridis_r', linewidth=0.3,
                       alpha = 0.8, edgecolor = 'k', norm=norm)
ax.scatter(25,35,4, c='k', depthshade=False, alpha = 1, s=100)

plt.show()
```

Comment: When I tried Axes3D I was getting a warning. It works however with plt.axes: "ax = plt.axes(projection ='3d', computed_zorder=False)". It took me a long time to find this solution. Thanks a lot!

Comment: This worked insanely well, thank you. Very clean, just one liner.

Answer (score 3):

Run into this problem in 2020 and do not want to switch to another package. This solution is a modification of [Will](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4741979/will)'s answer above. Basically draw the circle in three axis to make it more like a dot. Also use ellipse to adjust for axis ratios. Works better if you set the radius smaller and choose a face color:

[image]

```
   def add_point(ax, x, y, z, fc = None, ec = None, radius = 0.005):
       xy_len, z_len = ax.get_figure().get_size_inches()
       axis_length = [x[1] - x[0] for x in [ax.get_xbound(), ax.get_ybound(), ax.get_zbound()]]
       axis_rotation =  {'z': ((x, y, z), axis_length[1]/axis_length[0]),
                         'y': ((x, z, y), axis_length[2]/axis_length[0]*xy_len/z_len),
                         'x': ((y, z, x), axis_length[2]/axis_length[1]*xy_len/z_len)}
       for a, ((x0, y0, z0), ratio) in axis_rotation.items():
           p = Ellipse((x0, y0), width = radius, height = radius*ratio, fc=fc, ec=ec)
           ax.add_patch(p)
           art3d.pathpatch_2d_to_3d(p, z=z0, zdir=a)
```

where radius is the radius of the "circle", fc is the face color,  ec is the edge color.

The modified code:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D, art3d
from matplotlib.patches import Circle, Ellipse
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({10: {10: 1,15: 1,20: 1,25: 1,30: 1,35: 1,40: 1,45: 1,50: 1,55: 1,60: 1,65: 1,70: 1,75: 1,80: 1,85: 1,90: 1},
                   15: {10: 4,15: 1,20: 1,25: 1,30: 1,35: 1,40: 1,45: 1,50: 1,55: 1,60: 1,65: 1,70: 1,75: 1,80: 1,85: 1,90: 1},
                   20: {10: 6,15: 3,20: 1,25: 1,30: 1,35: 1,40: 1,45: 1,50: 1,55: 1,60: 1,65: 1,70: 1,75: 1,80: 1,85: 1,90: 1},
                   25: {10: 7,15: 5,20: 3,25: 1,30: 1,35: 1,40: 1,45: 1,50: 1,55: 1,60: 1,65: 1,70: 1,75: 1,80: 1,85: 1,90: 1},
                   30: {10: 9,15: 6,20: 4,25: 3,30: 1,35: 1,40: 1,45: 1,50: 1,55: 1,60: 1,65: 1,70: 1,75: 1,80: 1,85: 1,90: 1},
                   35: {10: 10,15: 7,20: 5,25: 4,30: 2,35: 1,40: 1,45: 1,50: 1,55: 1,60: 1,65: 1,70: 1,75: 1,80: 1,85: 1,90: 1},
                   40: {10: 11,15: 8,20: 6,25: 4,30: 3,35: 2,40: 1,45: 1,50: 1,55: 1,60: 1,65: 1,70: 1,75: 1,80: 1,85: 1,90: 1},
                   45: {10: 12,15: 9,20: 7,25: 5,30: 4,35: 3,40: 2,45: 1,50: 1,55: 1,60: 1,65: 1,70: 1,75: 1,80: 1,85: 1,90: 1},
                   50: {10: 13,15: 9,20: 7,25: 6,30: 5,35: 4,40: 3,45: 2,50: 1,55: 1,60: 1,65: 1,70: 1,75: 1,80: 1,85: 1,90: 1},
                   55: {10: 14,15: 10,20: 8,25: 7,30: 5,35: 4,40: 3,45: 3,50: 2,55: 1,60: 1,65: 1,70: 1,75: 1,80: 1,85: 1,90: 1},
                   60: {10: 15,15: 11,20: 9,25: 7,30: 6,35: 5,40: 4,45: 3,50: 3,55: 2,60: 1,65: 1,70: 1,75: 1,80: 1,85: 1,90: 1},
                   65: {10: 16,15: 12,20: 9,25: 8,30: 6,35: 5,40: 5,45: 4,50: 3,55: 2,60: 2,65: 1,70: 1,75: 1,80: 1,85: 1,90: 1},
                   70: {10: 17,15: 12,20: 10,25: 8,30: 7,35: 6,40: 5,45: 4,50: 4,55: 3,60: 2,65: 2,70: 1,75: 1,80: 1,85: 1,90: 1},
                   75: {10: 18,15: 13,20: 10,25: 9,30: 7,35: 6,40: 5,45: 5,50: 4,55: 3,60: 3,65: 2,70: 2,75: 1,80: 1,85: 1,90: 1},
                   80: {10: 19,15: 14,20: 11,25: 9,30: 8,35: 7,40: 6,45: 5,50: 4,55: 4,60: 3,65: 3,70: 2,75: 2,80: 1,85: 1,90: 1},
                   85: {10: 21,15: 14,20: 11,25: 10,30: 8,35: 7,40: 6,45: 6,50: 5,55: 4,60: 4,65: 3,70: 3,75: 2,80: 2,85: 1,90: 1},
                   90: {10: 23,15: 15,20: 12,25: 10,30: 9,35: 8,40: 7,45: 6,50: 5,55: 5,60: 4,65: 3,70: 3,75: 3,80: 2,85: 2,90: 1}})




xv, yv = np.meshgrid(df.index, df.columns)
ma = np.nanmax(df.values)
norm = matplotlib.colors.Normalize(vmin = 0, vmax = ma, clip = True)

fig = plt.figure(1)
ax = Axes3D(fig)
surf = ax.plot_surface(yv,xv,df, cmap='viridis_r', linewidth=0.3,
                       alpha = 0.8, edgecolor = 'k', norm=norm)

add_point(ax, 25, 35, 0, radius=1)
add_point(ax, 25, 35, 2, radius=2)
add_point(ax, 25, 35, 4, radius=3)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be to plot the point as a spherical surface.
Then you can just plot the 'point' on top of the surface.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).