# How to not show the axes planes (xy, yz and xz) in mplot3d?

Tags: python, matplotlib, mplot3d

I want my plot to look like this without those walls of planes:
[image]

But when I use mplot3d, I get this:
[image]

How to I remove the walls at the edges?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Matplotlip: 3D surface plot turn off background but keep axes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44001613/matplotlip-3d-surface-plot-turn-off-background-but-keep-axes)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure you can turn that off the panes but you can access its child properties and make them transparent if you wish.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.tri as mtri


fig = plt.figure(figsize=[15, 8])

# Make a mesh in the space of parameterisation variables u and v
u = np.linspace(0, 2.0 * np.pi, endpoint=True, num=50)
v = np.linspace(-0.5, 0.5, endpoint=True, num=10)
u, v = np.meshgrid(u, v)
u, v = u.flatten(), v.flatten()

# This is the Mobius mapping, taking a u, v pair and returning an x, y, z
# triple
x = (1 + 0.5 * v * np.cos(u / 2.0)) * np.cos(u)
y = (1 + 0.5 * v * np.cos(u / 2.0)) * np.sin(u)
z = 0.5 * v * np.sin(u / 2.0)

# Triangulate parameter space to determine the triangles
tri = mtri.Triangulation(u, v)

# Plot the surface.  The triangles in parameter space determine which x, y, z
# points are connected by an edge.
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 2, 1, projection='3d')
ax.plot_trisurf(x, y, z, triangles=tri.triangles, cmap=plt.cm.Spectral)
ax.set_zlim(-1, 1)

ax.xaxis.set_pane_color((1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0))
ax.yaxis.set_pane_color((1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0))
ax.zaxis.set_pane_color((1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0))
# make the grid lines transparent
ax.xaxis._axinfo["grid"]['color'] =  (1,1,1,0)
ax.yaxis._axinfo["grid"]['color'] =  (1,1,1,0)
ax.zaxis._axinfo["grid"]['color'] =  (1,1,1,0)
```

[image: transparent panel]

Comment: This is exactly the same answer provided as a duplicate five days ago.