# how to change color of axis in 3d matplotlib figure?

Tags: matplotlib

The color of the axis (x, y, z) in a 3d plot using matplotlib is black by default. How do you change the color of the axis? Or better yet, how do you make them invisible?

```
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.xaxis.set_visible(False)  # doesn't do anything
```

And there doesn't seem to  be a `ax.xaxis.set_color` function. Any thoughts on how to make the axis invisible or change the color?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine your method with the approach provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19576145/4932316). I am showing an example that affects all three axes. In Jupyter Notebook, using tab completion after `ax.w_xaxis.line.`, you can discover other possible options

```
ax.w_xaxis.line.set_visible(False)
ax.w_yaxis.line.set_color("red")
ax.w_zaxis.line.set_color("blue")
```

To change the tick colors, you can use

```
ax.xaxis._axinfo['tick']['color']='r'
ax.yaxis._axinfo['tick']['color']='g'
ax.zaxis._axinfo['tick']['color']='b'
```

To hide the ticks

```
for line in ax.xaxis.get_ticklines():
    line.set_visible(False)
```

[image]

Comment: Works great. Is there a similar functionality for the color/visibility of the ticks?

Comment: Great again! Can I go for three in a row? Howbout making the ticks invisible? I tried `t = ax.w_xaxis.get_ticklines()`, then loop `for a in t: a.set_visible(False)`, no error message, but also no invisible ticks.

Comment: I got it to work doing `ax.xaxis._axinfo['tick']['inward_factor'] = 0` and 
`ax.xaxis._axinfo['tick']['outward_factor'] = 0`. Kinda ugly really. But it works. Better suggestions are appreciated!

Comment: I also don't understand why the simple `ax.w_xaxis.set_visible(False)` doesn't do anything. But the suggested fix work great.

Comment: Sorry, @Sheldore, that last edit with the for loop to make the ticks invisible doesn't work (in mpl 3.1.1). Besides, it drives me bunkers to have `ax.xaxis` and `ax.w_xaxis`. What's the diff?